# I want color of menu in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

- I want change color of menu in wordpress.
- I'm using boostrap.
- My menu currently looks like below image:

[image]

My code make menu in `header.php`

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(

'theme_location'    => 'primary',
'container'         => 'nav',
'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

) );
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add this css.

It is for only active menu:

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a:hover {
        color: #FFF;  
    }


     .navbar-nav>li.active>a, .navbar-nav>li.active>a:hover {
        color: #FFF;  
    }
```

It is for all menu.

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
        color: #FFF;  
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
        color: #FFF;  
    }
```